# Unexpected result receiving from Connections API- https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=12345/connections ?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is this is an issue or something else ? 
since from long time i am accessing LinkedIn user connection count form this endpoint, which suddenly started wrong connection number in response.

Is there any changes happened in response or else i need to consider in response ?

can anyone guide me here?

Answer (score 0):

Is LinkedIn server give other type of data?
Try to filter out the un-desired type.

[Network Update Types](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/network-update-types)

Comment: I dig into response and found that it give me two nodes in response: one a List of connection named,"connections", which count is less than my actual LinkedIn Connection  on profile , second node named "Total" which contain only integer count which actually match with my connection count

Comment: can anyone guide me here ? what is the difference between this two counts ? and why this happened ? From when this change happened at LinkedIn

Comment: On Feb this year, LinkedIn announced a API change. This could be the root cause of change happened.
I don't know why, but i suffered from this change as well.
Hope this help.